# Сообщение "Это не похоже на отладочную сборку."

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator

Qt Creator начал выдавать сообщение
[image: сообщение]

Вчера отладка работала. Сегодня запускает с выводом вот этого сообщения и, соответственно, никакие точки остановки не работают!

Режим сборки - "Отладка"

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 3):

Разобрался.

Виной всему был флаг **CONFIG += c++11 release**

Сделал **CONFIG += c++11 debug_and_release** и все пришло на круги своя....